# comparing lines with awk vs while read line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, search

I have two  files one with 17k lines and another one with 4k lines. I wanted to compare position 115 to position 125 with each line in the second file and if there is a match, write the entire line from the first file into a new file. I had come up with a solution where i read the file using 'cat $filename | while read LINE'. but it's taking around 8 mins to complete. is there any other way like using 'awk' to reduce this process time.

my code

```
cat $filename | while read LINE
do
  #read 115 to 125 and then remove trailing spaces and leading zeroes
  vid=`echo "$LINE" | cut -c 115-125 | sed 's,^ *,,; s, *$,,' | sed 's/^[0]*//'`
  exist=0
  #match vid with entire line in id.txt
  exist=`grep -x "$vid" $file_dir/id.txt | wc -l`
  if [[ $exist -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "$LINE" >> $dest_dir/id.txt
  fi
done
```

Comment: Just so we're clear, you want to take cols 115-125 of file A, and if those 11 characters match any full line in file B, print the full file A line?

Comment: Yes thatz right, also I want to remove the trailing spaces and leading zero's from the cols 115-125 which is taken from file A and compare it with full line in file B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work, updated to strip white space:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# NR is the current line number (doesn't reset between files)
# FNR is the line number within the current file
# So NR == FNR  takes only the first file
NR == FNR {
    # Mark the current line as existing, via an associative array.
    found[$0]=1

    # Skip to the next line, so we don't go through the next block
    next
}
{
    # Take the columns we're looking for
    cols = substr($0,115,11)

    # Strip whitespace (space and tab) from the beginning (^) and end ($) 
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"", cols)
    gsub(/[ \t]+$/,"", cols)

    # Check the associative array to see if this was in the first file
    # If so, print the full line
    if(found[cols]) print;
}
```

Put it in a file and call with one of the following

```
awk -f script.awk patterns.txt full.txt
./script.awk patterns.txt full.txt
```

Comment: Your script took just 3 seconds to complete where mine taken over 17 minutes. Thank you somuch Kevin.

Comment: Kevin,
Can you please explain the code and its iteration
especially if(found[cols]) print;

and

NR == FNR {
        found[$0]=1
        next
}

Comment: @user37774 Sure, I've added explanation to the code.

Comment: When you do `found[cols]` you're actually allocating and setting (to nothing) `found[cols]`. Doing `found[$0]` (without `=1`), and then test with `if(cols in found)` is a lot more efficient (memory and cpu-wise).